# Minimum Image Object Size in macOS Pages 7.1?

Tags: pages

Hello everyone: here's one for you! I'm trying to build a new WP layout in Pages 7.1 (NOT a WP doc) and want to include images (objects) within the text box. Seems there's a minimum size you can reduce images to, beyond which Pages will not move. Am I right - or missing something obvious? Apple's documentation in this area is typically vague...

Hope you can help!

Gary H.

Answer (score 5):

OK - fixed it... If you select an image from the Media browser, you HAVE to select 'Other' to select your image otherwise the image you end up with WILL NOT BE ABLE TO BE RESIZED BELOW A MINIMAL THRESHOLD... how nuts is *that*???

Comment: I am on pages v8.1. I guess "Other" is renamed to "Choose" now. With that I am able to resize freely, but if I go via "Insert" menu and Image Gallery, then there is a stupid minimum threshold!

Comment: I must be an idiot but when I insert it through "Choose" there was no way for me to resize it, I gave up and used Libre Office instead.